# Select-string to grab time format from a log file entry

Tags: string, powershell, select-string

I am trying to pull date and time from the similar string below:

```
<![LOG[Inventory: Successfully sent report. Destination:mp:MP_SinvEndpoint, ID: {CFF6CD46-AEC7-4BFB-8B09-E7507346AAF6}, Timeout: 80640 minutes MsgMode: Signed, Not Encrypted]LOG]!><time="14:30:50.088+300" date="09-24-2013" component="InventoryAgent" context="" type="1" thread="4448" file="agentstate.cpp:2038">
```

I am using these declarations:

```
$Sinv = Select-String $env:windir\syswow64\ccm\logs\inventoryagent.log -pattern "SinvEndpoint" -SimpleMatch | select-object -last 1

$Hinv = Select-String $env:windir\syswow64\ccm\logs\inventoryagent.log -pattern "HinvEndpoint" -SimpleMatch | select-object -last 1

$DDR = Select-String $env:windir\syswow64\ccm\logs\inventoryagent.log -pattern "DdrEndpoint" -SimpleMatch | select-object -last 1
```

I am trying to identify in which order each of their last entries happen (based on timestamp in its string) and then I will write code accordingly.

Comment: String didn't copy over:  <![LOG[Inventory: Successfully sent report. Destination:mp:MP_SinvEndpoint, ID: {CFF6CD46-AEC7-4BFB-8B09-E7507346AAF6}, Timeout: 80640 minutes MsgMode: Signed, Not Encrypted]LOG]!><time="14:30:50.088+300" date="09-24-2013" component="InventoryAgent" context="" type="1" thread="4448" file="agentstate.cpp:2038">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to extract date and time information with something like this (assuming you have PowerShell v3 installed):

```
$file    = "$env:windir\syswow64\ccm\logs\inventoryagent.log"
$pattern = 'SinvEndpoint.*<time="(.*?)" date="(.*?)"'

$Sinv = Select-String $pattern $file | select -Last 1 | % {
          $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value + ' ' + $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I hope I have a moment to try this tomorrow, looks promising!

Comment: Thanks!  This in fact grabs the last entry(of one of the entry types) as requested!  Again, I am brand new when trying to output these.  Since the $pattern is static, I assume I would need to create 2 additional for each string pattern ie HinvEndpoint, DDREndpoint?  Then my final questions is, from the values returned for each, the next step is to find a method to find the newest value of the three date patterns, say from, todays date?  Again, thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, you need 2 more expressions for the other two keywords, since you want the last date for each of the keywords. To get the most recent date of the three values convert the strings into actual dates, `sort` them (default order is ascending), and `select` the last item from the result.

Comment: Thanks!  If the values are in this format: 09-27-2013 13:54:42.040+300, will powershell be able to look at the date and then the time natively, or do I need to do additional scripting?  I will need to consider if the entries are from the same day and then the time.  I took a basic class a few years ago on 1.0 so if you have any online recommendations to aid in my naivety, I will humbly look over them:).

Comment: Okay, I hope I am going in the right direction.  I declared the remainder of the variables and then came up with the following: $array = $ddr, $sinv, $hinv; then I did this which seems to get the latest entry: (get-variable array).value | Sort-object | select -last 1; however it is only giving the variable string value, which I would like for it to return potentially the variable name to work with.  I will look further.  Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: If `MM-dd-yyyy` is the date format of your locale you should be able to convert it to a date like this: `Get-Date '09-27-2013 13:54:42.040+300'`. Otherwise move the year to the front (`yyyy-MM-dd`) before passing the timestamp into `Get-Date`. As for your last question, I suggest you provide more information about what you're actually trying to achieve by doing this.

Comment: Ultimately I am needing to find the latest entry of the three, differentiate if it is either from a ddr, hinv, or sinv entry coming in last place.  It if is a ddr entry, I will add code to re-install the SCCM client on the machine, otherwise the other entries that may come in last place will be looked at based on their normal scheduled inventory cycle based on business requirements and potentially write code accordingly to update their inventory if it is out of date.  Thanks so much!  Btw Sapien has authored a free version of a powershell 1.0 book which is filling it some gaps for me:)

Comment: Okay, I think I have it.  I am not sure how it pulls this back from the objects but when I did if statements it pulls back what I need: $array = @($ddr, $sinv, $hinv); $LastOne = (get-variable array).value | Sort-object | select -last 1; [br]: PS C:\Users\b_budde\Documents> if ($lastone -eq $hinv) {"True"
} else {"False"}
False
[br]: PS C:\Users\b_budde\Documents> if ($lastone -eq $sinv) {"True"
} else {"False"}
False
[br]: PS C:\Users\b_budde\Documents> if ($lastone -eq $ddr) {"True"}
 else {"False"}
True

Comment: @user2755028 Better use a [`switch` statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx) for things like that.

Comment: Fantastic Ansgar!  I will post new code using switch instead and repost!

Comment: $array = @($ddr, $sinv, $hinv)
$LastOne = (get-variable array).value | Sort-object | select -last 1
switch ($LastOne) {$DDR {"DDR"} $Sinv {"SINV"} $Hinv {"HINV"} Default {"Unknown"}}